# Cannot convert from Node<E> to Node<E>?

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I am just doing some practice from one of my books, and I was curious about why I am getting the following error in eclipse:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from type DoublyLinkedList.Node<E> to DoublyLinkedList.Node<E>`

Code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.ListIterator;
    import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


public class DoublyLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Iterable<E>{

 private int size = 0;
 private Node<E> head;
 private Node<E> tail;

/** Returns a list iterator object for the list at 
 * the specified index
 */

 public DoublyLinkedList(){


}



private static class Node<E> {

    Node<E> next = null;
    Node<E> prev = null;
    E data;

    public Node(E dataItem){
        data = dataItem;
    }

    public Node(E dataItem, Node<E> previous, Node<E> nextNode){
        this(dataItem);
        prev = previous;
        next = nextNode;
    }

}


private class MyListIter<E> implements ListIterator<E>{

    private Node<E> lastReturned; // a link reference to the last item that was returned
    private Node<E> nextItem; // a link reference to the next item in the list
    /** The index of the current position */ 
    private int index = 0;

    public MyListIter(int pos){
        if (pos < 0 || pos > size)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index: " + index);
        lastReturned = null;
        if (pos == size){
            index = size;
            nextItem = null;
        } else { // otherwise we will start at the beginning of the list, and loop until the position in the argument
            nextItem = head; // ERROR
            for (index = 0; index < pos; index++){
                nextItem = nextItem.next; // next item will always reference the list node that is called by the next method
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(E element) {
        if (head == null){
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(element);
            head = newNode; // ERROR
            tail = head;
        }


    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return nextItem != null; // just checks to make sure there is a node following the current node
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return (nextItem == null && size != 0) || nextItem.prev != null;
    }
    @Override
    public E next() {
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("There is no node at that location");
        lastReturned = nextItem;
        nextItem = nextItem.next;
        index++;
        return lastReturned.data;
    }
    @Override
    public int nextIndex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public E previous() {
        if (!hasPrevious())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        if (nextItem == null) // the iterator is at the end of the list
            nextItem = tail; // therefore, the nextItem is at the tail, so the previous is the tail. ERROR HERE TOO
        else
            nextItem = nextItem.prev;
        lastReturned = nextItem;
        index--;
        return lastReturned.data;
    }
    @Override
    public int previousIndex() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void remove() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void set(E arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}


@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


}
```

I commented where exactly I am getting the error in 3 different locations. If you can provide any feedback, I'd appreciate it. My book doesn't address it and I have searched around and can't really seem to get the answer i'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've declared two different generic types: `E` (for `Node`) and `E extends Comparable<E>` (for `DoublyLinkedList`).

The main issue here is probably `MyListIter`, which is a non-static inner class and as such automatically inherits `DoublyLinkedList`'s definition of `E`. Because it inherits the definition of `E`, you should just be declaring it as

```
private class MyListIter implements ListIterator<E>
```

but you've made it `MyListIter<E>`, which is redefining `E` to something different than the `E` that `DoublyLinkedList` users (implicit `E extends Object` vs. `E extends Comparable<E>`).

I *think* `Node` should work as-is since it is a nested class (with the `static` keyword) and doesn't inherit the definition of `E` from `DoublyLinkedList`. However, it'd probably make sense here to declare it as a non-static inner class of `DoublyLinkedList` (`private class Node`) the same as `MyListIter`.

Also, you should probably allow `E` to be a type that is a *subtype* of some type that implements `Comparable` by declaring it as `E extends Comparable<? super E>`.

Comment: Wow. I never would have known. I think that fixed everything. This book really is poorly written. I was under the impression that if DoublyLinkedList is type <E>, that everything within that class should be <E> also, making them all the same type. But I guess its not?

Comment: @TMGunter: If you declare an inner class without the `static` keyword, instances of that inner class all must belong to a specific _instance_ of the containing class. For that reason, they automatically have access to the generic type(s) declared for the containing class (`E` in this case). I'm actually not sure that `Node` is a problem here since it has the `static` keyword and is therefore a nested class that doesn't inherit the definition of `E`. `MyListIter` is probably the real issue here, since it does inherit the definition of `E` but also declares its own (conflicting) definition.

Comment: Thank you. That actually clarified things quite a bit. I am actually understanding generics, nested (static and non-static) classes, and inheriting types much more now.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're getting this error because you're redefining `E` in your `Node` nested class. Since it's a static nested class, it has no direct relationship to the parent class `DoublyLinkedList`. It might make more sense to make the class non-static so that `E` continues to have meaning within it. For example:

```
private class Node {

Node next = null;
Node prev = null;
E data;

...
```

**EDIT:** as ColinD noted, `MyListIter` should similarly not redeclare `E` as a type parameter. Changing this like with `Node` should fix the issue.

Comment: When I do that it complains about my Node constructor not being generic and says, "The type DoublyLinkedList<E>.Node is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <E>"

Comment: did you make sure to change all `Node<E>` types to `Node`?

Comment: Yeah. Node<E> is now type Node. I also used Colin's suggestion to make E a subtype of ?. My book doesn't really go into that at all, but I think I understand what it means. I had to look it up. It makes a lot more sense that I make Node a private nested class, and remove its static nature. I was trying to follow my book, and I think it just really isn't teaching it very well.

Answer (score 1):

ColinD is right (+1).

To understand what's going on, imagine not using the same formal type parameter 3 times, but E for DoublyLinkedList, F for Node and G for MyListIter. Then the error message would say `Type mismatch: cannot convert from type DoublyLinkedList.Node<E> to DoublyLinkedList.Node<G>`. The solution is the one ColinD suggested. If you want, you can leave `Node<F>` static, with the fix all instances will have the same actual type parameter.

Comment: So I can really define the static class "Node" any type I really want to? When I use a reference to Node<E> in the top-level class, even though Node is defined as Node<F>, it will inherit the type "E" from the parent class? That is what i'm gathering. If I do not make it a static inner class, I should not define the Node with a type-parameter because the type "E" would be inherited from the top-most class?

Comment: For clarity: in `public class DoublyLinkedList<E  ...` you define the formal type parameter `E`, and then you can use E in the body and any inner class. Therefore, you can also declare a `private Node<E> head;`, just the same way as for instance `private Node<String> head;` or `private List<E> head;`. Just as the formal type parameter for List is totally independent of your `E` and could be `F` or anything else, the formal type parameter of your `private static class Node<F>` is. That's why I suggested using different letters, to avoid confusion.